# Android can't I force onDraw() method of a customView?

Tags: android

I looked up on the logs and it seems that onDraw() method of a customView is called not when it is instantiated but after the onCreate() method of the activity. Meaning

```
onCreate(){
     log1
     CustomView CV = new CustomView();
     log2
}
class CustomView{
      onDraw(){
           log3
      }
}
```

leads to log1->log2->log3..
But I have some codes using the drawn customview in onCreate which means it should have finished the onDraw() method at the instantiation of the View.
CV.invalidate does not work... please help

Comment: Consider moving those code for the onDraw to `onPostCreate` function perhaps?

Comment: why you want drawing of custom view to be complete before onCreate() finsih ?

Comment: @Elye I couldn't found how to get the canvas of the customView's onDraw(Canvas canvas)... Instead I moved the codes needed into onDraw() thanks for the comment

Comment: @umerk44 I had to get the canvas' information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
onCreate(){
  CustomView cv = new CustomView();
  ... draw something 
}

class CustomView{
   onDraw(){
   }
}
```

to

```
onCreate(){
  CustomView cv = new CustomView();
  cv.initialDraw = true;
}
class CustomView(
  boolean initialDraw = false;

  onDraw(){
    if(initialDraw){
      ...draw something
      initialDraw = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I tried all the solutions in the answers and thought yours will be the best for me since I only draw at its instantiation lol

Comment: This is not a great idea because there are many circumstances when your view will be asked to redraw itself.  You can't always control the way Android works the view hierarchy. onDraw should *always* just draw the view, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is not guaranteed to be visible during `onCreate()`, so that is not a good time to be doing anything that requires the view to exist on the screen.

`onCreate()` is a good time to perform layout and find the Views that you will need reference to later in the code, but it's not time to start drawing on the screen.

Instead, you should set the state of your views in the `onResume()` method.  `onResume() will execute immediately afterward your activity becomes visible.  You will be guaranteed to have your views drawn by then.

Comment: didn't use it this time but I'll keep in mind that layouts aren't made that fast.. I thought they'd be made already by setContentView..

Answer (score 0):

onDraw() does not happen until after Android has measured and laid out all the views.  This process definitely does not happen during onCreate() and is not tied to the activity lifecycle.

If you need to know when an onDraw() occurs, you should register an [OnDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) callback on the [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) for the current view hierarchy. Use [View.getViewTreeObserver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getViewTreeObserver%28%29) to get an instance of this.